# EXCEL - VBA - copying data from forEach loop

Tags: excel, vba

This is my second time posting here, and I hope somebody will help me:

I have a Excel file with data about work hours that have been put in. I already have made a macro that changes and sorts the initial wroksheet as well creates worksheets with names of all workers.
The part where I am stuck is the forEach loop.
Here is what i have so far:

```
 ' Creating a range of sheet names from the data on Members
    Dim SheetNamesRange As Range
    Set SheetNamesRange = Sheets("Members").Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

    ' Iterate through all sheets in the range and write the word "Updated" in cell B2
    Dim SheetName As Variant, SheetNameString As String
    For Each SheetName In SheetNamesRange
    
        ' OVDJE SAM ISKOMENTIRAO OVA 2 REDA
        SheetNameString = CStr(SheetName)
        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetNameString).Range("Q2") = "Updated"
```

What I would like it to do is:
Loop through all the data in the first worksheet named "Shifts", according to the names of employees (i have the list of all employees in the 3rd worksheet named "Members"), find all of the relevant data to each of the members (i.e. find all the data regarding "member1") and copy to his worksheet I created before, and loop this until all the data has been copied to its respective worksheet.

If you need more info let me know!
Kind regards and thanks in advance

Comment: Does `Shift`'s data also start in `A1`? Are the names of employees in it also in column `A` starting from `A2`?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. In both worksheets (Shifts and Members) the employee names start at A2